# Include .ttf font into pdf generated with Flying Saucer and Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, flying-saucer

I only managed to generate the pdf with .ttf font included only if I have provided the absolute path in the index.html like this:

```
        @font-face {
        font-family: Asap-Regular;
        src: url("/home/user/Desktop/Asap-Regular.ttf");
        -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
        -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
        }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to integrate the .ttf font as a relative path. I've also tried to integrate from java code like this:

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(("path/Asap-Bold.ttf"),
                                       "Asap-Bold", "Identity-H", true, null);
```

and it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging Flying Saucer some time it seems that:

```
_sharedContext.setBaseURL(url);
```

that needs to point to .ttf file path(in my case it was resources dir). In order to set the url from sharedContext you need to call:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html, String.valueOf(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:fonts/").getURI()));
```